# Does changing a Nintendo ID remove or make unusable preinstalled games?

Tags: wii-u, nintendo-network-id

I purchased a preowned Wii U with 11 game discs, the system itself is the Zelda Wind Waker HD deluxe edition. If I add my Nintendo ID and remove the old one does that make the game on there unplayable for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

All digital content for Nintendo (as of right now) is tied to:

1. Your Nintendo Network ID (NNID)
2. Your system

So technically Wind Waker HD was the previous owner's, and if they ever bought a Wii U again, they'd have to call Nintendo Support and hope they allow them to put that game on their new system.

If you don't remove the old NNID, you can play WWHD on your own personal NNID. (As an example, I have Pikmin 3 digital tied to my NNID, but when my wife logs on with hers, she can still play Pikmin 3).